# What does Gibbs Energy represent physically?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

I was reading about Thermodynamics in Chemistry.

I know that Enthalpy change at a constant pressure by a system is actually released as heat by the system.

---

My question:

What exactly does Gibbs Free Energy and its change represent physically (on a similar note to what Enthalpy represents)?

---

To me Gibbs Energy seems very non-intuitive and more like a magical number which can predict the feasibility of a process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gibbs Free Energy represents the energy that is free to do useful work for a spontaneous process. In other words, it is the max work done by a process (at constant $T$ and $P$). The Gibbs free energy can tell us whether a process will proceed spontaneously or not.

The Gibbs free energy is not magical. Instead it is derived from the inequality

$$dS \ge \frac{dQ}{T}$$

which states that in a reaction, the change in entropy must always be greater than or equal to the heat transferred/$T$. If we consider the enthalpy for constant pressure

$$\Delta H_p = \Delta U + P\Delta V$$

and since

$$\Delta U = Q + W$$

we get

$$\Delta H_p = Q + W + p\Delta V$$

with $W = - P\Delta V$ then $\Delta H = Q$, and using the inequality above, we get

$$TdS \ge dH$$

and if we integrate and rearrange we get

$$\Delta G = \Delta H - T\Delta S$$

which is the Gibbs free energy and therefore has to be negative for a reaction to proceed spontaneously.

Comment: "The Gibbs Free Energy represents the energy that is free to do useful work for a spontaneous process. In other words, it is the max work done by a process (at constant  and )." . Can you elaborate on what exactly does it mean?